# How to mesure the duration taken from a block of code in the dart

Tags: dart

I have as an example this block of code :

```
for(int index = 0; index < 1000000; index+=1) {
 print(i);
}
```

is there any way to measure the time/duration taken by this to finish in the milliseconds

without using external source, I mean any idea to do it in the dart ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Stopwatch`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.4/dart-core/Stopwatch-class.html) class which makes it easy to measure time:

```dart
void main() {
  Stopwatch stopWatch = Stopwatch()..start();

  for(int index = 0; index < 1000000; index+=1) {
    print(index);
  }

  print('Time it took: ${stopWatch.elapsedMilliseconds}ms');
}
```